# Vuforia Unity3D: how to make on-screen close/back/quit button?

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I just started making AR application.

I made the first, working, could not be happier. But I have a problem: I do not know how to insert a button on the screen that will close the app when user tap (yes, tap, I want to work on Android) on it.

So when I run the application, which I made in Unity, I see only camera. I want to put in the corner of the screen a button that will always stand there and that will close the application. This button I need because I can not close the application using the "Back" button.

I use a Nexus 7 2013 (android 5.0) because only there application works. On the Galaxy S2 4.4.4 I have always crashes (can't run, only splash screen). But that is another problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Unity's GUI function

```
void OnGUI() {
   if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Exit"))
      Debug.Log("Clicked the exit button");
      Application.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem and have found the answer. You CAN actually close the application with the back button! I find the answer here https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/android-back-key-not-working-unity-extension-imagetarge

> 1. create a new C# script in your assets
> 2. rename it, and open it (the default MonoDevelop by Unity will be opened to edit the script)
> 3. write this code into the script:
>
>    public void Update () {
>
>    ```
>        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
>
>            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)) {
>
>               //quit application on return button
>
>               Application.Quit();
>
>               return;
>
>           }
>
>        }
>    ```
> 4. save it, and you can close the editor
> 5. in the 'hierarchy' tab, you can click on 'ImageTarget' component and then click the 'add element' in the inspector, then choose
>      'script' option and choose the script that you've just made (I choose
>      'ARCamera' component instead and it still works)

hope this helps, and though I'm probably too late for your project, I hope the people who encounter same problem in the future would be helped by this :)